# exchange server setup internal and external domain are different

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2007

i am plaining to install exchange 2013 , my internal domain name is abc.local

And external Domain name is xyz.com

now want to create my email id on xyz.com (external) this is ideal situation .

I am adding my external domain to alternative UPN suffix in ad

And creating a zone in my dns with external (xyz.com) now my dns have 2 zone..(abc.local and xyz.com) Now I am

confused about my records (autodiscover, mail,mx)

Where exactly I will create these records  ? in  internal zone or external   ?

Please suggest

If I am doing anything wrong pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

You'll be taking email from xyz.com so you'll only want an MX record for xyz.com in your "external" zone (public DNS record).  Point that record to whatever IP your SMTP receiver/mail gateway lives on.  Validate with mxtoolbox.com.

An example:  I have an MX record of abc.com.  It's IP is a public IP on my firewall.  That NATs to a DMZ IP which lives on an Ironport mail gateway.  The Ironport mail gateway then delivers the mail to Exchange CAS SMTP receiver configured to only listen to the Iornport internal IPs.  Works great.

From there, you configure xyz.com as an authorative domain in Mail Flow (via Exchange Admin Center) via: [Configure an accepted domain within your Exchange org...](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj657734(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Your recipient policy should auto create emails based off this domain when you build a mailbox and from there you'll be able to test.  After that, worry about outbound, a whole different process.

-Chase

Comment: Oh yea, you don't need anything for the internal domain if you don't plan on receiving email from it.  If so, you can sure add an internal MX record to your internal DNS.  Not recommend because there's rarely a need.